# Align 2 columns to a container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a template that I am modifying to my liking. It is a container (blue) with no margin or padding, and inside a loop in which shows the products (red). I want to show 2 products per line, with a width of 49% and a space or margin of 2% so that everything is 100% wide (49 + 2 + 49 = 100). The problem is that if I add margin it is not aligned. What forms are there to do this?

UPDATE:

The container (blue) is inside another container that is float. Not only do I have 2 products (red), it is a dump of 20 products per page.

I want the products on the left side of the container (product1, product3, product5 ...) to be aligned to the left of the div.container. The products on the right side (product2, product4, product6 ...) are aligned to the right of the div.container and between them there is a margin or space.

[image]

Comment: Please post your relevant code =)

Comment: Look into CSS Box Sizing: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Comment: Have you tried using Flexbox?

Comment: @snkv yes I tried with your example but the result has been that they have all aligned in the same row, I give you an example, sorry for not drawing it completely horizontally. http://i.imgur.com/2MCaA2n.png

Comment: @Mike , what seems to be the problem? Have you tried using my example below on the `.container`? You need to couple it with `flex-wrap`, so the items can stack properly.

Comment: @snkv Yes that was the mistake. Sorry, I do not know about FlexBox yet. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply take advantage of the **[flexbox model](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)** and spare yourself some time. Use **[prefixes](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)**!

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: teal;
  width: 480px;
}

.main-element {
  margin-bottom: .7rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
}

.element-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.element {
  width: 49%;
  height: 220px;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main-element"></div>
  <div class="element-container">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using flex, all products (20) are aligned in the available width, not only exist 2. Sorry for not explaining well, now I update the example

Comment: @Mike, have you even tried using my example? The `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between` can be applied to the `div.container` that you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Use percentages for your width on the divs. Percentage is based on the parent element, not the body unless the body is the parent element - so make sure that they are the children of a parent that represents the final width and than add these two properties to the CSS for the two child blocks:

```
width:49%;
margin: 0 .5% 0 .5%;
```

Or, you could target first child and last child with the following in order to only place the gutter in between the two divs.

```
.parentdiv:fist-child{
    margin-right: 1%;
    width:49%;
}
.parentdiv:last-child{
    margin-left: 1%;
    width:49%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the margin is effecting BOTH of the divs, so it is actually 49 + 2 + 49 + 2 leaving you with 102%, causing it to break down to the next line.

So to answer, change your margin to 1%